# Measuring low Input Bias current of cmos op amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-measurement, input-bias-current

I am trying to test the input bias current of the following CMOS RRIO Opamp: [TP2412](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809251517_3PEAK-TP2414-SR_C248721.pdf)
I am going to follow some similar circuits like these two shown in another op amp datasheet.

[image: figure1]
[image: figure2]

I know that these are the most basic versions of the test circuits but since I am trying to get a measurement as simply as possible, is it feasible for me to build a circuit like the one in the second picture and use a simple switch like the CD4066 to then measure the voltage across the capacitor after the switch is opened and find my input bias current via Ic = C*dV/dT or am I missing crucial components/information?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you not happy with the values specified in the data sheet for some reason?

Comment: @Sephiroth need a reference to those images.

Comment: @VoltageSpike its the datasheet for LMC660: (page 11 and 12)  https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Flmc660

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were measuring input bias current myself, I would use this circuit.

[image]
https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/simple-op-amp-measurements.html

> The circuit is the same as the offset circuit of Figure 2, with the
> addition of two resistors, R6 and R7, in series with the DUT inputs.
> These resistors can be short circuited by switches S1 and S2. With
> both switches closed, the circuit is the same as Figure 2. When S1 is
> open, the bias current from the inverting input flows in Rs, and the
> voltage difference adds to the offset. By measuring the change of
> voltage at TP1 (=1000 Ib–×Rs), we can calculate Ib–; similarly, by
> closing S1 and opening S2 we can measure Ib+. If the voltage is
> measured at TP1 with S1 and S2 both closed, and then both open, the
> "input offset current," Ios, the difference between Ib+ and Ib–, is
> measured by the change. The values of R6 and R7 used will depend on
> the currents to be measured.

Comment: I actually tried this circuit (on a breadboard to be fair) and the results were insufficient. I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that the rated bias current for the op amp I am trying to test is .3 pA and this is unable to measure accurately with resistors (to my understanding)

Comment: Breadboard or soldered breadboard?

Comment: breadboard, my next design will be on a pcb.

Comment: PnP Breadboards have nf of capacitance, they won't work for this kind of measurement. Use only soldering breadboards: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/large-solderable-breadboard-hookup-guide/all

Comment: okay will definitely be buying some of those! do you think I would be able to measure sub pico-amp currents with the circuit you provided?

Comment: Yes, you might have to have a regular PCB with a good ground plane. I think the biggest problem is the large amounts of capacitance with the regular breadboard, you will get better results with the soldering breadboard. Make sure you realize that each piece of metal has inductance and resistance and between conductors you have capacitance so minimizing those will help with the parasitics that might be a problem with precession circuits such as this

Comment: Okay cool I will start looking into how I can minimize that as much as possible, thank you so much for the advice!

Comment: If you like the question, please use the voting system. Thanks